# Cannot add foreign key constraint in Laravel Migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, database-migration

I've found dozens of similar issues posted, but none of the solutions have seemed to work in my case. When I run "php artisan migrate:fresh", it's throwing the error...

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table
>   `slicer_profiles` add constraint `slicer_profiles_user_id_foreign`
>   foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

- All tables created are InnoDB
- The 'users' table is being created before my table
- I've split the code in to two steps, assigning the foreign key afterwards

  ```
  Schema::create('slicer_profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
      $table->string('title');
      $table->text('description');
      $table->string('slicer');
      $table->string('machine');
      $table->softDeletes();
      $table->timestamps();
  });

  Schema::table('slicer_profiles', function($table) {
      $table->foreign('user_id')->unsigned()
          ->references('id')
          ->on('users')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
  });
  ```

I check the auth users table and it seems to use an UNSIGNED BIGINT, so I try setting ->unsigned() on the reference as well, but no change. Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `users.id` field is a BIGINT then your need to make the `users_id` column on `slicer_profiles` a BIGINT so that the 2 fields have exact matching types.

```
Schema::create('slicer_profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ...
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
    // or $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it instantly. I guess the tutorial I am following is a bit outdated, perhaps Laravel changed the 'id' on the 'users' auth table from an INT to BIGINT or something since it was written. Appreciate the help!

Comment: yea the adjustment for the `users` table to use `bigIncrements` is a newer change